# GAS search and download youtube programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

Is it possible to:

1. search video with keyword and duration > 1hour.
2. download it automatically.

Basic idea is from google apps script [YouTube Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube) and [search api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) document. there has below example:

```
function searchByKeyword() {
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    q: 'dogs',
    maxResults: 25
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < results.items.length; i++) {
    var item = results.items[i];
    Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s', item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
  }
}
```

The example can search keyword and print out the videoId, but I wish too add a length > 1 hour condition and download it automatically.

How can we implement such idea?

Comment: Questions to which the answer is either a short "yes" or a short "no" are often [not very good questions for on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Possibly. What does the API documentation say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot search by duration with such granular detail; you can only provide a filter parameter that searches for "short" (under 4 minutes), "medium" (4 minutes - 20 minutes), or "long" (more than 20 minutes). The parameter is "videoDuration," so your query function would look like this:

```
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    q: 'dogs',
    maxResults: 25,
    videoDuration: 'long',
    type: 'video'
  });
```

**EDIT**: Note that, when searching by videoDuration, you also have to include the 'type' attribute and set it to video.

Additionally, you cannot download YouTube videos; there is no API for this and it is against the terms of service.

Comment: It seems no such API "videoDuration" from the document: [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#properties), when I run it, I got a error message.

Comment: The link you provided in your comment is pointing at the wrong doc; that's the documentation for the videos->list endpoint (when you already know the video id), not the search->list endpoint. You can see the correct documentation here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list But you're right that there's an error, because there's a piece I left out; when searching by video duration, you also have to set the 'type' parameter to 'video' so that playlists and channels won't be returned. I've edited my answer accordingly.